# Why is my vector PNG pixelated when I zoom?

Tags: vector, png, pixelation, zoom

I have saved my vector image as a PNG from Adobe Illustrator, but when I open the saved PNG file & zoom in on it, the image becomes pixelated.. Why is it doing this?

Comment: png is not vector, so yes pixels will show up

Answer (score 5):

A `.png` image type is not vector and is a bitmap image. When you save a `ai` file as an image, it rasterizes it (makes it bitmap). If you want a vector filetype, then you will need to go to `File > Save as...` and choose  `.svg`, which is vector filetype.

Comment: Blame Macromedia Fireworks for making people think PNG is a vector file format - the application makes use of the file format's private chunks to store the proprietary information. See https://www.adobe.com/support/fireworks/export/fw_export_vs_sav/fw_export_vs_sav02.html (which may also be read as an attempt at openwashing).

Comment: I wrote once to the Png Working Group, and they were ok to the usage of png by Fireworks, because the policy of the spacification is something to build on top of. But I agree, they should have used another specific extension, like .fwks or something.

Comment: @Rafael: Adobe could have made *abundantly*  clear that the vector part of their PNGs is not compatible with other PNG viewers & editors. (Perhaps they do and nobody reads the manual.)

Comment: Yeap, they probably should have.